# perl net::pcap installation on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, perl

I am trying to run a perl script that uses Net::pcap but it doesn't work for me, I installed `libpcap-dev`, `libnet-pcap-perl` and `libpcap`.
After that I downloaded [Net:pcap](http://search.cpan.org/~saper/Net-Pcap-0.17/Pcap.pm) from CPAN, and now I don't know what should I do to install the package.

[image: fail to run script using Net::pcap]

Thanks,

Comment: please dont post image, post text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of installing CPAN modules but the easiest is to use `cpanm`. If you are going to be working with Perl, you really should install it:

```
sudo apt-get install cpanminus
```

Then, install your module:

```
cpanm install Net::pcap
```

Alternatively, you can install with:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::pcap'
```

For more choices, read the CPAN install guide: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html